# Graphing blank cells in form of gaps in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I'm graphing a set of data that has blanks in some cells. In the blank cells I have formulas and I have to keep the formulas. When I graph the data, the blank cells are graphed as zeros. I'd like to put gaps instead of zeros in the graph.
I tried right click on the graph > Select Data > Hidden and Empty Cells Settings > Show empty cells as Gaps. But this did not help!

Comment: Hi Sara, can you provide some screen shots? In Excel 2010, when I test this approach, a formula that evaluates to a null string is not displayed as a zero in my chart. http://imgur.com/3bopUId

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of putting zeros or empty strings try to put `#N/A`.

You can do it with a formula like `=IF([test],[value],NA())`.

This will allow the graph not to show the missing values as zeros, but if I understand your question, it is still not what you want, because you want the missing values to be represented as gaps, not as missing values.

The only way that I know of to see the gaps is to use a scattered graph.

As far as I know, all the graphs that make a line to join two points, do join two points, and don't have the concept of missing point. They just join the two closest points.

A solution could be to make a VBA macro that goes inside the graph and changes the color of each graph line when the data is missing.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem since I only had blanck cells either at the begining or at the end of the series. Thank you!

Comment: The comment on only scattered graph works, helped me. "The only way that I know of to see the gaps is to use a scattered graph."

Answer (score 0):

> A solution could be to make a VBA macro that goes inside the graph and changes the color of each graph line when the data is missing.

I have code, that modifies charts.
It works for cells with #N/A, also na() function. Like old excel did.
First, you need a module with public sub:

```
Public Sub FormatNA()
Dim myChart As ChartObject
Dim series_i As Integer, series_count As Integer
Dim values_i As Integer, values_count As Integer
Dim rows As Integer, r As Integer
Dim mySeries As Object
Dim myValues As Variant
Dim myPoint As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
' for each chart in active sheet
For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    ' Determine Chart Type
    Select Case myChart.Chart.ChartType
        Case xlLine, _
            xlLineMarkers, _
            xlLineMarkersStacked, _
            xlLineMarkersStacked100, _
            xlLineStacked, _
            xlLineStacked100, _
            xlXYScatter, _
            xlXYScatterLines, _
            xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers, _
            xlXYScatterSmooth, _
            xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
                ' for each series
                series_count = myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
                For series_i = 1 To series_count
                    ' for each data
                    Set mySeries = myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(series_i)
                    Set myPoint = mySeries.Points(1)
                    myValues = mySeries.Values
                    values_count = UBound(myValues)
                    ' global formatting:
                    Select Case mySeries.ChartType
                        ' MARKERS:
                        Case xlLineMarkers, _
                            xlLineMarkersStacked, _
                            xlLineMarkersStacked100, _
                            xlXYScatter, _
                            xlXYScatterLines, _
                            xlXYScatterSmooth
                                With mySeries
                                    .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = myPoint.MarkerForegroundColorIndex
                                    .MarkerForegroundColor = myPoint.MarkerForegroundColor
                                    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = myPoint.MarkerBackgroundColorIndex
                                    .MarkerBackgroundColor = myPoint.MarkerBackgroundColor
                                    .MarkerForegroundColor = myPoint.MarkerForegroundColor
                                    .MarkerSize = myPoint.MarkerSize
                                    .MarkerStyle = myPoint.MarkerStyle
                                End With
                        ' NO MARKERS, JUST LINE:
                        Case Else
                    End Select
                    With mySeries
                        .Border.Color = myPoint.Border.Color
                        .Border.Weight = myPoint.Border.Weight
                        With .Format.Line
                            .ForeColor.RGB = myPoint.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
                            .BackColor.RGB = myPoint.Format.Line.BackColor.RGB
                            .Weight = myPoint.Format.Line.Weight
                            .Visible = msoTrue
                        End With
                    End With
                    For values_i = 2 To values_count
                        ' set line invisible if #NA
                        If IsEmpty(myValues(values_i - 1)) And Not IsEmpty(myValues(values_i)) Then
                            mySeries.Points(values_i).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                            'mySeries.Points(values_i).Border.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' for debugging
                            'mySeries.Points(values_i).Border.Weight = 1
                        End If
                    Next values_i
                Next series_i
        Case Else
            ' different chart type
    End Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then, you'll have to trigger this sub everytime you calculate worksheet:
In ThisWorkbook define sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Static Calculated As Boolean
If Not Calculated Then
    Call FormatNA
    Calculated = True
Else
    Calculated = False
End If
End Sub
```

Maybe it's not perfect, but it works for me. [Sample of manipulated chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlLl9.png)

Answer (score 0):

May be it might be  Usefull any one how has this problem,

Step1: First get Chartpage access and use Display blank as

```
   Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

   chartPage.DisplayBlanksAs = Excel.XlDisplayBlanksAs.xlInterpolated;
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

As stenci said, it's difficult to create a gap without VBA due to the presence of formulas in the cells. A time consuming solution is to delete the formulas, which provided blank cells, one by one so that they will then graph as gaps. 
For a large dataset that might be too time consuming.

There's a workaround if you're willing to open and close the file:

1. Set the blank cell to appear empty. For example: =IF(COUNT(A1)>0,A1,"");
2. Save a copy of your workbook in your preferred format because the next step will eliminate the formulas;
3. Save the workbook as a .CSV file with a different file name;
4. Close the file. Then reopen the file;
5. Now a line graph will provide gaps for the empty cells.

Note that both sides of the gap need to have a line segment, i.e. at least two data cells on both sides of the gap. Specifically, this will graph a gap: 
A1=1, A2=2, A3=(blank), A4=4, A5=5.

And this will not graph a gap:
A1=1, A2=(blank), A3=3, A4=4.